# How to read string in bash

Tags: bash

My code

```
FOO="dsad; dsadasddas; dadsad; dsdsad asdsdd"
echo "${FOO%%;*}"   
result: dsad

FOO="dsad; dsadasddas; dadsad; dsdsad asdsdd"
echo "${FOO##*;}"
result: dadsad; dsdsad asdsdd
```

howto print all character for first semicolon?

```
FOO="dsad; dsadasddas; dadsad; dsdsad asdsdd"
echo "${FOO???}"
result: dsadasddas; dadsad; dsdsad asdsdd
```

howto print and all character before last semicolon?

```
FOO="dsad; dsadasddas; dadsad; dsdsad asdsdd"
echo "${FOO???}"
result: dsadasddas; dadsad; dsdsad asdsdd
```

help anyone? Thank you ;)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to print all character for first semicolon and how to print and all character before last semicolon. Thank

Comment: What's with the stars that appear and don't appear in the string and the output?

Comment: They marked bold text in the original question, but @shellter's edit made them literal.

Comment: sorry, I missed that. I don't see a way to roll back to the original. Doah!

Comment: You could have given a better string in example. Eg FOO="sin; cos; tan; cot; sec". Its very hard to interpret your output of echo.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#` and `%` instead of `##` and `%%`:

```
foo='one; two; three; four'

# All characters after first semicolon
echo "${foo#*;}"  # two; three; four

# All characters before last semicolon
echo "${foo%;*}"  # one; two; three
```

`${var##glob}` and `${var%%glob}` will take away as much as possible (greedy matching). `${var#glob}` and `${var%glob}` will take away as little as possible (reluctant matching).